# SQL statement / stored procedure to replace NULL values in single table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2017

Very new to SQL and I've been presented with the following problem. I apologize if it's a simple fix. All the replacement questions I've looked at this morning didn't seem to solve this exact problem.

I'm using SQL Server 2017 and I have a table similar to the following, the actual table is 100k+ rows but follows this format, it just has more individual items and columns:

```
ColA    ColB    ColC    ColD    ColE    ColF
----    ----    ----    ----    ----    ----
ROW1    Item1   2341    Null    Null    Null
ROW2    Item2   7953    Null    Null    Null
ROW3    Item1   Null    2342    Null    Null
ROW4    Item2   Null    9827    Null    Null
ROW5    Item1   Null    Null    1945    Null
ROW6    Item2   Null    Null    0745    Null
ROW7    Item1   Null    Null    Null    1298
ROW8    Item2   Null    Null    Null    2356
```

Is there a way to programmatically update the table so that ROW1 and ROW2 would have all the non NULL values for columns D, E, and F?

Comment: What are you trying to replace the NULLs in rows 1 and 2 with? Values in the same column from row 3 and 4?

Comment: The non NULL values in ColD - ColF for Item1 and Item2 in rows 3-8.  The goal would be to end up with two rows with all non NULL values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These 2 statements should get you what you're after. if you're only after a `SELECT` statement, the first one is what you're after. If you want to actually `UPDATE` all the rows, then you want the one with the CTE:

```
USE Sandbox;
GO

CREATE TABLE dbo.Tab (ColA char(4),
                      ColB char(5),
                      ColC char(5),
                      ColD char(5),
                      ColE char(5),
                      ColF char(5));
INSERT INTO dbo.Tab (ColA,
                     ColB,
                     ColC,
                     ColD,
                     ColE,
                     ColF)
VALUES('ROW1','Item1',2341,Null,Null,Null),
      ('ROW2','Item2',7953,Null,Null,Null),
      ('ROW3','Item1',Null,2342,Null,Null),
      ('ROW4','Item2',Null,9827,Null,Null),
      ('ROW5','Item1',Null,Null,1945,Null),
      ('ROW6','Item2',Null,Null,0745,Null),
      ('ROW7','Item1',Null,Null,Null,1298),
      ('ROW8','Item2',Null,Null,Null,2356);
GO

SELECT ColA,
       ColB,
       MAX(ColC) OVER (PARTITION BY ColB) AS ColC,
       MAX(ColD) OVER (PARTITION BY ColB) AS ColD,
       MAX(ColE) OVER (PARTITION BY ColB) AS ColE,
       MAX(ColF) OVER (PARTITION BY ColB) AS ColF
FROM dbo.Tab
ORDER BY ColB;
GO

WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT ColA,
           ColB,
           ColC,
           ColD,
           ColE,
           ColF,
           MAX(ColC) OVER (PARTITION BY ColB) AS ColCn,
           MAX(ColD) OVER (PARTITION BY ColB) AS ColDn,
           MAX(ColE) OVER (PARTITION BY ColB) AS ColEn,
           MAX(ColF) OVER (PARTITION BY ColB) AS ColFn
    FROM dbo.Tab)
UPDATE CTE
SET ColC = ColCn,
    ColD = ColDn,
    ColE = ColEn,
    ColF = ColFn;
GO

SELECT *
FROM Tab;

GO

DROP TABLE dbo.Tab;
```

Comment: Larnu, I think this will work great!  Going to modify it for the production table and will let you know.